# How to deserialize json object in windows store app

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-mvc-4

Here is my web api method.

```
public class EmployeeController : ApiController
{
    employee[] employee = new employee[]
    {
      new employee{Employee_Id=1,Employee_Name="Richa",Employee_Address="Noida",Employee_Contact=12567,Employee_Salary=5000},
      new employee{Employee_Id=2,Employee_Name="Megha",Employee_Address="Delhi",Employee_Contact=98754,Employee_Salary=5435},
      new employee{Employee_Id=3,Employee_Name="Gaurav",Employee_Address="Noida",Employee_Contact=33333,Employee_Salary=4233},
      new employee{Employee_Id=4,Employee_Name="Suyash",Employee_Address="Delhi",Employee_Contact=5555,Employee_Salary=2342},
      new employee{Employee_Id=5,Employee_Name="Manish",Employee_Address="Noida",Employee_Contact=84576,Employee_Salary=4555},
      new employee{Employee_Id=6,Employee_Name="Manish",Employee_Address="Noida",Employee_Contact=84576,Employee_Salary=4555},
      new employee{Employee_Id=7,Employee_Name="Ram",Employee_Address="Delhi",Employee_Contact=6456,Employee_Salary=4555},
      new employee{Employee_Id=8,Employee_Name="Rajesh",Employee_Address="Gaziyabad",Employee_Contact=8865,Employee_Salary=4555},
      new employee{Employee_Id=9,Employee_Name="Deepak",Employee_Address="Hapur",Employee_Contact=34242,Employee_Salary=4555},
      new employee{Employee_Id=10,Employee_Name="Naveen",Employee_Address="Gaziyabad",Employee_Contact=86756,Employee_Salary=4555},
      new employee{Employee_Id=11,Employee_Name="Rakesh",Employee_Address="Noida",Employee_Contact=8564,Employee_Salary=4555}
    };
    public IEnumerable<employee> GetAllEmployee()
    {
        return employee;
    }
```

consuming the above in windows store app

```
private HttpClient httpClient;

    public TestPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        httpClient = new HttpClient();
        httpClient.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:52333/");
        httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
        // Limit the max buffer size for the response so we don't get overwhelmed
        httpClient.MaxResponseContentBufferSize = 266000;
    }
    protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        GetEmployee();
    }
    private void Rectangle_Tapped(object sender, TappedRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
      //  easingAnimation.Begin();
    }
    private async void GetEmployee()
    {
        var response = await httpClient.GetAsync("api/employee");
        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            var employee = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            List<Test> result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Test>>(employee);

            //var emp = JsonArray.Parse(employee);
            //var qry = from m in emp
            //          select new
            //          {
            //              Emp_Id = m.GetObject()["Employee_Id"].GetNumber(),
            //              Emp_Name = m.GetObject()["Employee_Name"].GetString(),
            //              Emp_Address = m.GetObject()["Employee_Address"].GetString(),
            //              Emp_Contact = m.GetObject()["Employee_Contact"].GetNumber(),
            //              Emp_Salary = m.GetObject()["Employee_Salary"].GetNumber()
            //          };
          //  employee_details.DataContext = qry;
        }
    }
}
```

but all the fields have default values like null and 0.
shall i add  the same class reference employee from rest service at my client side?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your class "Test" should have same properties as "Employee" class:

> Employee_Id, Employee_Name, Employee_Address, Employee_Contact,
>   Employee_Salary

When you retrieve value from ReadAsStringAsync(), you will retrieve string, so that string needs to contain Json data in string from your async call.

You need to check in debugger if:

```
var employee = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
```

employee has any value?

If yes, then you just deserialize in Test:

```
List<Test> result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Test>>(employee);
```